# How to show the total number of records at the end of the page

Tags: crystal-reports, record-count

I would like to show total number of records at the end of the page using Crystal Reports. If there are no records I would like to display the count as `0`.

Comment: Do you want the total number of records displayed on every page footer? Or, do you want the total displayed once in the report footer?

Answer (score 1):

- [MSDN Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/189f369c-a95a-4af5-b6ba-12cbd701a03c)

If you don't feel like clicking, here is the solution provided:

> "Change Summary operation" and using the "Count" field
>   is a formula : `count({your filed})`
>   if no rows, `count({your filed})` will return `null`.
>   so, you can create a new formula filed to replace your Σ 。
>   the formula: 
>   `if isnull(count({your filed})) then 0 else count({your filed})`

Answer (score -3):

Well, one thing you can do is add a field to the resultset that is the count of the number of the records in the result set.

It may not be the prettiest solution; the count has to appear in every row returned.  When I last used Crystal Reports (pushing two years ago now), I don't recall a single report being capable of handling results from multiple data sources.

Comment: I have at least one report at the moment running against two different SQL Server databases at the same time.